# How to build mysql docker image with custom value for max_allowed_packet?

Tags: mysql, docker

How to build mysql docker image with custom value for max_allowed_packet?

```
#my-custom.cnf
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=64M
```

```
#Dockerfile
FROM mysql/mysql-server:5.7 
RUN echo "Custom mysql build" 
COPY ./my-custom.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/
RUN echo "Listing customized configurations" && cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/lj-mysql.conf
```

The customized mysql container still shows 4MB only.

```
mysql> show variables like '%max_allowed_packet%';
+--------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name            | Value      |
+--------------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet       | 4194304    |
| slave_max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------------+------------+
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can resolve this with an imperative command

`docker run -it -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<sql-pw> mysql:5.7 --max-allowed-packet=67108864`

And other way is to using `docker-compose`

```
version: "3"
services:
  data:
    image: "mysql:5.7.20"
    #(it is 64 mb mean 67108864 bytes)
    command: --max_allowed_packet=67108864
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_password
```

Use of docker-compose is a good way to start a docker containers and easy to work with docker-compose.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the custom CNF file override doesn't work? It's per MySQL's own instruction! (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You should use docker volume for such purposes. Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.

```
docker run -d -v ./my-custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/ mysql/mysql-server
```

This will mount your local config on your host machine into docker container and will run mysql in detached mode.

Comment: This one did not work either ! In fact, this was the first preferred approach after reading the official documentation from mysql - https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: No errors reported. Executing a command with max_allowed_packet=<> in docker-compose.yml works. This approach is marked as answer.